# pandas: get rows by comparing two columns of dataframe to list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas DataFrame with four columns: A,B,C,D.

```py
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,4,9], 'B': [1,7,5,7],'C':[1,1,1,1],'D':[2,2,2,2]})
```

I also have a list of tuples:

```py
my_tuples = [(0,1),(4,5),(9,9)]
```

I want to keep only the rows of the dataframe where the value of `(my_df['A'],my_df['B'])` is equal to one of the tuples in my_tuples.

In this example, this would be row#0 and row#2.

Is there a good way to do this? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `DataFrame` created by tuples, there is no `on` parameter for default interecton of all columns in both `DataFrames`, here `A` and `B`:

```
df = my_df.merge(pd.DataFrame(my_tuples, columns=['A','B']))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  1  2
1  4  5  1  2
```

Or:

```
df = my_df[my_df.set_index(['A','B']).index.isin(my_tuples)]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  1  2
2  4  5  1  2
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `map`.

```
my_df.loc[list(map(lambda x: x in my_tuples, zip(my_df['A'], my_df['B']))),:]

#my_df.loc[[row in my_tuples for row in zip(my_df['A'], my_df['B'])],:]
```

**Time comparison**

```
%%timeit
my_df.loc[list(map(lambda x: x in my_tuples, zip(my_df['A'], my_df['B']))),:]
394 µs ± 24.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df = my_df.merge(pd.DataFrame(my_tuples, columns=['A','B']))
3.56 ms ± 248 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%%timeit
df = my_df[my_df.set_index(['A','B']).index.isin(my_tuples)]
3.99 ms ± 139 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Timings are nice if test in large data, if test with few rows output of test should be really different. Sometimes fastest solution in smal df is slowiest with large DataFrame.

Comment: I don't think this can ever be slower

Comment: @ansev That is a really cool answer.  So cool I cannot quite parse it.  But I will endeavor to understand...